# Yocto Custom Device Tree

Tags: tree, device, yocto, bitbake

I am trying to add a custom device tree to my yocto build.

Input dts directory is located: arch/arm/boot/dts/

Output DTB directory is located: build/tmp/deploy/images/machine-name

I added my custom DTS file to the input dts directory, and included it in the makefile, however after I bitbake, I do not see any generated file in the output DTB directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I am having issues figuring out how to remove a feature from my device tree. If I wanted to remove i2c how would I go about this? I know I can just edit my DTS file, but I would like it to be built into the recipe, so when you run bitbake one time it automatically disables/removes whatever peripheral/device/driver.

Thank you!

Comment: You have to create a recipe, which adds your own file and compiles it. Then you have to create an own machine which uses your device tree. This is not a basic procedure unlike you build your device tree blob manually like described e.g. here: http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Build+Device+Tree+Blob

Comment: meta-phytec is doing this: https://git.phytec.de/

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:**

For simple changes it is recommended to use device tree overlays if supported.

See: [rpi: Device Trees, overlays, and parameters](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md)

---

If you do not want to just extend or patch the device tree but use a complete file  you can create a simple bbappend blueprint for your kernel-recipe with recipe tool

```
recipetool appendsrcfile -wm colibri-imx7 ../layers/meta-mylayer/ virtual/kernel your.dts  'arch/${ARCH}/boot/dts/your.dts'
```

which looks like this:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
PACKAGE_ARCH = "${MACHINE_ARCH}"

# adding your device tree to the kernel sources
SRC_URI += "file://imx7d-colibri-emmc-mydevie.dts;subdir=git/arch/${ARCH}/boot/dts"

# compile your device tree
SRC_URI += "file://0001-compile-my-devicetree.patch"

# make dt available for kernel build things.
KERNEL_DEVICETREE_append = " imx7d-colibri-emmc-mydevice-v3.dtb "
```

The patch of the Makefile is needed to compile the new file it in a standard buildchain

```
diff --git a/arch/arm/boot/dts/Makefile b/arch/arm/boot/dts/Makefile
index b0e966d..9bbd52c 100644
--- a/arch/arm/boot/dts/Makefile
+++ b/arch/arm/boot/dts/Makefile
@@ -568,6 +568,7 @@ dtb-$(CONFIG_SOC_IMX7D) += \
    imx7d-cl-som-imx7.dtb \
    imx7d-colibri-emmc-eval-v3.dtb \
    imx7d-colibri-eval-v3.dtb \
+   imx7d-colibri-emmc-mydevice.dtb \
    imx7d-nitrogen7.dtb \
    imx7d-pico-pi.dtb \
    imx7d-sbc-imx7.dtb \
```

now you can ether select the device tree blob at uboot prompt

```sh
setenv fdt_board=mydevice
printenv
boot
```

or patch uboot to use the blob as default

Comment: recipetool appendsrcfile -wm colibri-imx7 ../layers/meta-mylayer/ virtual/kernel your.dts  'arch/${ARCH}/boot/dts/your.dts'
> why your.dts at the end of /dts / here?